# Why theoretically the higher voltages do not generate the bigger losses

Tags: voltage

Why theoretically the higher voltages do not generate the bigger losses  voltage is the amount of electrical potential energy that each coulomb of charge has, so then independent of the current when each such coulumb passes through the electric resistance left out more of its potential energy  and a higher voltage drop.

This my question is primarily based on the distribution of electricity.

And I know what generates losses in the distribution network  I'm interested
 me why the higher voltage does not produce any greater losses because every colomb of carge possesses more potential energy.

Comment: This is not just "theoretically" but very much the case in practice as well. In fact, so much so, that companies invest many milions if not bilions of dollars/euros in research for the 800kV and 1MV powerdistribution networks.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say we want to transfer a power "P" over a distribution line. Assume two ways to do this:

Higher voltage lower current: P = V1*I1 where I1 = P/V1

Lower voltage higher current: P = V2*I2 where I2 = P/V2

Thus V1 > V2 and I1 < I2

Any distribution channel will have definite resistance "R"

Power loss in both cases:

Power loss 1 = I1*I1*R = P*P*R / V1

Power loss 2 = I2*I2*R = P*P*R / V2

Since V1 > V2, Power loss 1 < Power loss 2

Hence it's preferred to transmit power at higher voltages and lower currents.

Answer (score 1):

*because every colomb of carge possesses more potential energy.*

**NO** charge does **not** contain any energy. The energy is in the **movement** of charge.

The voltage or potential has nothing to do with this. Suppose a wire is at + 1000 Volts compared to ground. Now I compare that to **two** other wires, Wire A which is also at +1000 Volts and wire B which is at ground level potential. Depending on how I measure the voltage my original wire has either 0 Volt (I measure against Wire A) or +1000 V (when I measure against wire B). Same wire, same amount of charge trapped in the wire. How could that in any way influence the energy?

What the potential difference allows is **current to flow**. This flow contains the energy. Against wire A there is no voltage difference so no current can flow so no energy can be extracted.

Against wire B it is a different story, there is a voltage difference of 1000 V so I can connect a load to make a **current** flow and this releases the electrical energy.

So remember: A coulomb is an amount of charge and thus a fixed number of electrons. It says **nothing** about how much energy is there. One Coulomb in a box gives you **zero** energy. Only if you can make that Coulomb of charge flow to somewhere else (through a conductor) can it release energy. But the energy is not in the charge itself. It is in the movement of the charge.

Comment: coulomb of charge possesses potential energy or if you want the electrons because the source creates an imbalance in the charge between the two points what occurs when we connect the load between those two points when we connect the load between these two points the current flows and the current flows thanks to the source that has given the potential energy and now the electrons want to return to the state in which they were performing the work on the load this is more known as a voltage

Comment: You're still missing the point that the voltage potential by itself has nothing to do with losses. The losses are due to **current flowing**. Power is voltage x current. So higher voltage means less current at the same power. That lower current means less losses.

Answer (score 0):

> independent of the current when each such coulumb passes through the electric resistance left out more of its potential energy and a higher voltage drop.

I don't know where you got that idea from.  The voltage drop across any given section of transmission line depends on the current flowing, and is totally independent of the supply voltage.

If a given section of line has a resistance R, and a current of I is flowing, then the voltage drop is given by `Vd = IR`.  The original supply voltage doesn't appear in this equation.

The power lost in that section of line is then `P = Vd I = I² R`.  Again, the supply voltage has no effect on the power lost.

So to transmit the most power with the minimum loss, it is best to increase the supply voltage and decrease the current.

Comment: coulomb of charge possesses potential energy or if you want the electrons because the source creates an imbalance in the charge between the two points what occurs when we connect the load between those two points when we connect the load between these two points the current flows and the current flows thanks to the source that has given the potential energy and now the electrons want to return to the state in which they were performing the work on the load this is more known as a voltage –